# Property names of objects in IEnumerable property do not follow the configured naming strategy

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, json.net

When I serialize an class that has an IEnumerable property, the properties of the objects in the IEnumerable do not follow the configured Naming Strategy.

```
services
  .AddOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>()
  .Configure<IHttpContextAccessor>((options, httpContextAccessor) => {
    options.UseCamelCasing(true);
  });
```

```
public class MyViewModel 
{ 
  public string Name { get; set; }
  ...
  public IEnumerable Items { get; set; }
}

public class MyListItem {
  public string Text { get; set; }
  public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetItems(TId id)
{
  var vm = new MyViewModel { 
    Name = "MyViewModel",
    Items = new List<MyListItem> { new MyListItem { Text = "A", Value = "1" }  }
  };

  return Json(vm);
}
```

```
results:
{
  name: "MyViewModel",
  items: [{ Text = "A", Value = "1" }]
}
```

If I serialize the IEnumerable directly, the naming convention is respected.

```
var jsonOptions = ViewContext.GetService<IOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions>>();
var serializerSettings = jsonOptions.Value.SerializerSettings;
var vm = new MyViewModel { 
  Name = "MyViewModel",
  Items = new List<MyListItem> { new MyListItem { Text = "A", Value = "1" }  }
};


JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm.Items, serializerSettings);
```

```
results:
[{ text = "A", value = "1" }]
```

Is there any way to get this class to serialize correctly?

Comment: Is there any chance you are calling `UseCamelCasing(true)` in some places and [`UseMemberCasing()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcnewtonsoftjsonoptionsextensions.usemembercasing) elsewhere?  Looking at the [reference source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.NewtonsoftJson/src/DependencyInjection/MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptionsExtensions.cs#L26) these methods don't replace the contract resolver, they just set the naming strategy. ...

Comment: ... but since `DefautContractResolver` caches all contracts, if you use change the naming strategy after generating some initial contracts, you will continue to get the same contracts with the old naming strategy.  Rather than replacing the naming strategy, if you are mixing strategies you should just use a fresh resolver.

Comment: It’s only the one call in startup, then the options are supplied by DI; UseMemberCasing is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation it turns out that this is an issue with how Telerik KendoUI for AspNetCore serializes the settings, after searching through the source code it turns out that they are manually serializing the settings object, which is why it isn't respecting the configured settings.

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure AddControlers in startup (or program if you use) file

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

...

services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
  options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
        new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

Comment: Doesn't options.UseCamelCasing(true) do the same thing? It works on everything except the IEnumerable property.

// AddControllersWithViews is called in startup

Comment: @Failwyn I use this code and it never failed. I don't  see any sense to try something else

Comment: I just tested this and it has the same result as UseCamelCasing(true), the items of the IEnumerable property are not serialized with camel cased property names. In all other cases, everything is serialized as expected, it's just when using IEnumerable as the type that it's not working.